# is there a way to block swapping of slots of azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-policy

In my organization, we have setup of master branch of asp.net core app targeting to azure app service and other braches targeting to slots of same azure app service.
We have a requirement block any user in azure portal or any azure devops YAML pipeline's service connection to swap a slot of any azure app service.

- Is there an azure policy which can enforce this rule.
- If not then can we create service connection that can only either target azure app service or a slot in that app service

Comment: I am afraid service connection cannot only target azure app service. You can try turning off Auto Swap for your azure app. And set a branch policy in azure repo to disable editing the yaml file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Policy is not user aware, so you can not block. This should be possible using RBAC.